# Fourier transformation - connection between exponential and trigonomeric forms

Tags: fourier-analysis

On Wikipedia i have come across a Fourier transformation equation in exponential form and its inverse ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)):

$$
\begin{split}
\mathcal{F}(x) &= \int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}\mathcal{f}(k) \, e^{2 \pi i kx} \, \textrm{d} k\\
\mathcal{f}(k) &= \int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty}\mathcal{F}(x) \, e^{2 \pi i kx} \, \textrm{d} x
\end{split} 
$$

but i allso found that there is a trigonometric form of Fourier transformation ([PDF, page 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine_transforms))

$$
\begin{split}
\mathcal{F}(x) &= \int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(k) \cos(kx) \, \textrm{d}k\\ 
\mathcal{f}(k) &= \int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty} \mathcal{F}(x) \cos(kx) \, \textrm{d}x 
\end{split}
$$

**MAIN QUESTION:**

Could someone show me, how these pairs of equations are connected?

**SUB QUESTION:**

(i) I think that $\textrm{d}x$ is used for spatial integration *(please correct me if i am wrong).*

(ii) I think that $\textrm{d}k$ is used for integration over wave vector *(please correct me if i am wrong) .*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know about [Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)?

$e^{ix} = cos(x) + isin(x)$

I think that's a hint...

Also, see this formula
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine_transforms#Fourier_inversion
The first one in this column is simply the fourier integral applied over the above relation.
Everything else is just a simplification into cosine

And this is even better...a whole justification of the connection
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine_transforms#Relation_with_complex_exponentials

Comment: Second link you provided is suplying link between time dependant and frequency dependant fourier. I have wave vector ependant and spatial dependant fourier.

Comment: Call it time or frequency or wave or space --- the formulas are the same, no?